# Access to Httphandlers based on Ip

Tags: dart

I have current created a console application which has an Http handler for robots to post information about their location.
I would like to know how to enforce Ip based authentication in DART so that only robots with specific IP address can access the handlers and others get the 404 error if accessed.

```java
//The handler is registered as acceptInput
server.addRequestHandler((req) => req.path =='/acceptInput',acceptInput);
//Below is the code of the function
void acceptInput(HttpRequest request,HttpResponse response){
     //Some logic
}
```

I need to add authentication mechanism for making sure only specific ips can access this handler.

I could not find any useful resources specific to this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily authentication, but have you tried looking at [`HttpRequest`'s `connectionInfo.remoteHost`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpConnectionInfo.html)?

eg:

```dart
server.addRequestHandler(validate,acceptInput);

bool validate(req) {
  // only return true if the path + ip match
  return req.path =='/acceptInput' && req.connectionInfo.remoteHost = '1.2.3.4';
}

void acceptInput(HttpRequest request,HttpResponse response){
     //Some logic
}
```